# Checking the state of menu items inside handlers

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

How to check pro-grammatically whether command contributed as menu item(s) is/are checked/unchecked(If of CHECK BOX type), selected or unselected(if of type RADIO button) inside handlers **"execute"** method.
See snap shot here https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3pxBGD-v-ycWVFaeElnSGdyTE0/edit .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution,
Added this code in handler execute method method

```
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {

   Event selEvent = (Event) event.getTrigger();
   MenuItem item = (MenuItem) selEvent.widget;

   System.Out.Println(item.getSelection());     
   return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out this blog: http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2009/01/15/toggling-a-command-contribution/

So, first of all ensure that your command has appropriate style:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
  <menuContribution locationURI="...">
    <command commandId="org.eclipse.example.command.toggle"
              style="toggle" />
  </menuContribution>
</extension>
```

Then, you can check the state like this:

```
ICommandService service =(ICommandService) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(ICommandService.class);
Command command = service.getCommand("org.eclipse.example.command.toggle");
State state = command.getState("org.eclipse.example.command.toggleState");
System.out.println(state.getValue());
//state.setValue(!(Boolean) state.getValue());
```

Also, consider taking a look at org.eclipse.ui.handlers.HandlerUtil, it might be sometime helpful.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have created this command pro-grammatically. I got a solution now. Code is like this(I have added this snippet to my handler execute method )[CODE] public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
 
     Event selEvent = (Event) event.getTrigger();
     MenuItem item = (MenuItem) selEvent.widget;
     System.Out.Println(item.getSelection());
     
     return null;
}